# Cannot destructure property 'IdEvento' of 'this.store.selectSnapshot

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

Hi I am trying to show a modal when I press a button but I get the following error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'event id' of 'this.store.selectSnapshot (...)' as it is undefined." What could be happening?

[image]

this method should open the modal

```
  handleListar(item: IGeneral) {
    this.store.dispatch(new FormActividadSolContainerActions.ListarDatosHistorial({ IdEvento: item.nro }));
    const dialogRef = this.dialogService.openXL(ModalHistorialCambiosComponent);    
  }
```

this is the error line

```
  private loadGridHistorial = () => {
    const { IdEvento: IdEvento } = this.store.selectSnapshot(CONTAINER_STATE_TOKEN);
    this.store.dispatch(new ContainerActions.ListarDatosHistorial({ IdEvento }));
  }
```

my model

```
export class FormHistorialModel {  
  title = 'Detalle Del Historial';   
  gridHistorial: { loading: boolean; definition: IDataGridDefinition; source: IDataGridSource<any> } = {
    loading: false,
    definition: {
      columns: [
        { label: 'Numero de Evento', field: 'idEvento' },
        { label: 'Nombre de Evento', field: 'nombreEvento' },
        { label: 'Tipo de Evento', field: 'tipoEvento' },
        { label: 'Fecha del Cambio', field: 'fechaCambio' },
        { label: 'Cambio y Motivo', field: 'cambioyMotivo' },
        { label: 'Usuario', field: 'usuario' },          
      ]
    },
    source: {
      items: [],
      page: 1,
      pageSize: 10,
      total: 0
    }
  };
  formType = FormType.CONSULTAR;
  IdEvento: number = null;    
}
```

action

```
  export class ListarDatosHistorial {
    static readonly type = '[FORM-ACTIVIDAD-SOL-CONTAINER] ListarDatosHistorial';
    constructor(public payload: { IdEvento: number }  ) { }
  }
```

state

```
  listarHistorialSolicitudesBegin = (
    ctx: StateContext<FormHistorialModel>
  ) => {
    const state = ctx.getState();
    ctx.patchState({
      gridHistorial: {
        ...state.gridHistorial,
        loading: true
      },
    });
  }

  listarHistorialSolicitudesSuccess = (
    ctx: StateContext<FormHistorialModel>
  ) => (items: any[]) => {
    const state = ctx.getState();
    ctx.patchState({
      gridHistorial: {
        ...state.gridHistorial,
        loading: false,
        source: {
          ...state.gridHistorial.source,
          items,
          pageSize: items.length,
          total: items.length,
        }
      },
    });
  }

  listarHistorialSolicitudesError = (
    ctx: StateContext<FormHistorialModel>
  ) => (error) => {
    const state = ctx.getState();
    ctx.patchState({
      gridHistorial: {
        ...state.gridHistorial,
        loading: false
      },
    });
  }

  @Action(ContainerActions.ListarDatosHistorial)
  asynclistarHistorial(
    ctx: StateContext<FormHistorialModel>,
    { payload }: ContainerActions.ListarDatosHistorial
  ) {
    this.listarHistorialSolicitudesBegin(ctx);
   
    return this.historialService.ListarHistorial(payload.IdEvento).pipe(
      tap(response => {
        
        this.listarHistorialSolicitudesSuccess(ctx)(
          response.data || []
        );
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        this.listarHistorialSolicitudesError(ctx)(err);
        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }
```

service
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure in this but I believe `selectSnapshot` only returns a callback of the entire state object. You then need to point to the piece of state you want in order to get the value you are looking for.

Example from [ngxs.io/concepts/select#snapshot-selects](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select#snapshot-selects)

```
@Injectable()
export class JWTInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = this.store.selectSnapshot<string>((state: AppState) => state.auth.token);
    req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });

    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by just putting in a break point/debugger statement and see what you snapshot is returning:

```js
private loadGridHistorial = () => {
    const state = this.store.selectSnapshot(CONTAINER_STATE_TOKEN);
    debugger; // now inspect the state variable
    this.store.dispatch(new ContainerActions.ListarDatosHistorial({ IdEvento }));
  }
```

If it isn't working, then try changing from the state token to the state class name `this.store.selectSnapshot(ContainerState);`